# In Ruby how to put multiple lines in one guard clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following line of code :

```
if params[:"available_#{district.id}"] == 'true'
    @deliverycharge = @product.deliverycharges.create!(districtrate_id: district.id)
    delivery_custom_price(district)
end
```

Rubocop highlight it and asks me to use a guard clause for it. How can I do it?

EDIT : Rubocop highlighted the first line and gave this message `Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression`

Comment: which line did rubocop highlight? can you show us the complete message that rubocop gave you? (don't put it in the comments, edit your question and add it there because this info should be part of your question).

Comment: @TarynEast Just added the full msg :-)

Comment: Start by looking up "rubocop guard clause"; it's pretty self-explanatory: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/GuardClause

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't know what the surrounding code looks like so let's assume your code is the entire body of a method. Then a guard clause might look like this:

```
def some_method
  return if params[:"available_#{district.id}"] != 'true'   #guard clause

  @deliverycharge = @product.deliverycharges.create!(districtrate_id: district.id)
  delivery_custom_price(district)
end
```

Comment: Actually I want to run the last two lines only if the condition is true

Comment: @EApubs That's exactly what this code does. It does not proceed if the condition is false; this is the same thing as proceeding if the condition is true.

Comment: To guard a loop instead of a function definition, you can use "break if" on the first line of the loop